# Input from any file in WPF Application is very Slow

Tags: c#, wpf, file-io, desktop-application

I have a WPF Application which takes an input file path from user and then at the backend open the text file and try to read single character from the file.

```
        fs = File.OpenRead(fileName);
        var sr = new StreamReader(fs);

        int c;
        while ((c = sr.Read()) != -1) 
        { 
            Console.Write((char)c); //to check character read from file
            try
            {
                frequencyMap.Add((char)c, 1); 
            }
            catch
            {
                frequencyMap[(char)c] += 1;
            }
        }
```

Here frequencyMap is the dictionary in which character and it's frequency is stored.
This is one method no matter whatever i do the reading from file is always slow even if i try to read the whole text. On output window i see

[image]

Area selected is the part of input from the file.
Files upto 2KBs are fine but reading from files like 20KB really gives a hard time.

Now I read that using threads can solve this problem i just don't know how.

My Question is how can i read data from files fastly? if using threads is the solution then how to implement it?

i am new to this so kindly help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't read it by character, read it for example by line, and process each string in a loop. Also `Exception` is not a way to check if the key exists in the Dictionary.

```csharp
using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream) 
    {
        string s = sr.ReadLine();
        Debug.WriteLine(s); //to check string read from file
        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            if (frequencyMap.ContainsKey(c))
                frequencyMap[c]++;
            else
                frequencyMap.Add(c, 1); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I hope the Console.WrieLine is purely test code. Writing to the console for every character will slow down your processing considerably.

Secondly, it appears from the screen shot you shared that your application is throwing a lot of exceptions. Throwing exceptions is not cheap either in a tight loop.

Thirdly I would recommend you profile your application (visual studio provides a profiler) to help you pin point where exactly your application is spending it’s time.